# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for definite integrals... assume continuity?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

So here's the problem:

I can evaluate the indefinite integral:

```
Integrate[D[u[x], x], x]
```

> ```
> u[x]
> ```

However, I'd like to evaluate:

```
Integrate[D[u[x],x], {x, x0, x1}]
```

and get

> ```
> u[x1] - u[x0]
> ```

Or especially, evaluate

```
Integrate[D[u[x, y], x], {x, x0, x1}]
```

and get

> ```
> u[x1, y] - u[x0, y]
> ```

Is there a way that I can assume that `D[u[x], x]` is continuous in the range x0 to x1?  Is there a some assumption that can be met in order for me to evaluate the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Sorry, Integral=Integrate.  I've edited that.

That may work, but specifically, I'm trying to evaluate:
Integrate[ D[u[x, y], x] + D[u[x, y], y], {x,x0,x1}]

Or even: Integrate[ D[u[x, y], x,x] + D[u[x, y], y,y], {x,x0,x1}, {x,x0,x1}]

Comment: That may work, but specifically, I'm trying to evaluate:
Integrate[ D[u[x, y], x] + D[u[x, y], y], {x,x0,x1},{y,y0,y1}]

Or even: Integrate[ D[u[x, y], x,x] + D[u[x, y], y,y], {x,x0,x1}, {x,x0,x1},{y,y0,y1},{y,y0,y1}]

However, I think your approach may work.

Comment: Here you can find a doc explaining why it isn't possible in general http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that Mathematica can't guess that your functions are analytical and so complying with the hypotheses of the FToC.

An equivalent situation is this:

```
Limit[f[x], x -> x0]
(*
Limit[f[x], x -> x0]
*)
```

But:

```
Limit[f[x], x -> x0, Analytic -> True]
(*
f[x0]
*)
```

So you could use the ability of the `Limit[]` function to understand when a function is analytic to use the FToC as follows (sorry, it's trivial anyway):

```
k[x_] := Integrate[D[u[x], x], x]
Limit[k[x], x -> x1, Analytic -> True] -  Limit[k[x], x -> x0, Analytic -> True]
(*
-u[x0] + u[x1]
*)
```

Comment: FToC? what is that?

Comment: @Hector `Fundamental Theorem of Calculus` ...sorry lazy writer

Answer (score 0):

From your comment

> I'm trying to evaluate: Integrate[ D[u[x, y], x] + D[u[x, y], y], {x,x0,x1},{y,y0,y1}]

and if I understand correctly, this is kind of a negative answer.

If you plug this into *Mathematica* (v 9.0.1)

```
Integrate[D[u[x, y], x] + D[u[x, y], y], x, y]
```

you get this

$$\int u(x,y) \, dx+\int u(x,y) \, dy$$

which shows you that there are irreducible integrals there.

Comment: It'd be nice to know *why* those are irreducible, or what Mathematica needs to know about $u(x,y)$ to get the desired result.