# HeavisideTheta integration of derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am a bit confused, why *Mathematica* can not solve this task:

```
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[x] f''[x], {x, 0, xf}, Assumptions -> {∞ > xf > 0}]
```

Do I need some additional Assumptions for the Heaviside function? I would expect a solution like:

```
f'[xf]-f'[0]
```

Comment: possible dup of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42420/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-for-definite-integrals-assume-continuity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to help out [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) here.  The option [`Analytic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Analytic.html) needs to be set to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True.html).

```
SetOptions[Limit, Analytic -> True];
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[x] f''[x], {x, 0, xf}, Assumptions -> 0 < xf < ∞]
(* -Derivative[1][f][0] + Derivative[1][f][xf] *)
```