# Evaluating integrals of derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This one is so basic I anticipate having to hang my head in shame, but I haven't seen this asked or answered before, so here goes:

If I ask for

```
Integrate[f'[x], x]
```

Mathematica dutifully returns with `f[x]`, so that's fine. However, if I ask for

```
Integrate[f'[x], {x, a, b}]
```

Mathematica will not evaluate this to `f[b]-f[a]`. What am I missing?

Comment: First shot: if, e.g., $f'(x)=1/(x-a)^2$, then $\int_a^b f'(x)\textrm{d}x$ does not converge. MMA doesn't know if a general $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ makes sense.

Comment: check out: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126411/237

Comment: Good point. Is there a good way to tell Mathematica to not worry about f. Something like saying "f[x] is finite for all x"? Of course, Mathematica would need this information before or while evaluating the integral.

Comment: `SetOptions[Limit, Analytic -> True]`

Comment: Ahah! Got it, thanks!

Comment: I believe this summarizes things nicely. http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/